# Typewriter effect with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am just new to JavaScript I do not understand how can I create such Typewriter effect, I am having problem in changing the color of some of its words. I have made something like this [Sugar, Spice, everythingNice](https://amruthpillai.com/)

Comment: Just FYI, you can do a Typewriter effect in pure css.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well mate the website you wanted to build (i guess) is made up of three.js for that rotating cube and for the typing effect you can use a simple easy and yet powerful js library - Typed.js

Include this in your html file:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.12/typed.min.js"></script>


<h3>Hey i am a<span class="typing"></span></h3>
```

Configure some basic options such as what are the different words to type,speed and the container you want to insert it onto:

```js
   var typed = new Typed(".typing",{ //specify the element
    strings: ["Freelancer","Developer","Designer"], //multiple texts
     typeSpeed: 100,
     bacSpeed: 60,
     loop: true
   })
```

That's it! see it live below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Typed js basic usage</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.12/typed.min.js"></script>
        <style>
           *{
              font-family: sans-serif;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .typing{
               color: red;
            }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
         <h3>Hey i am a <span class="typing"></span></h3>
         
        <script>
          var typed = new Typed(".typing",{
        strings: ["Freelancer","Developer","Designer"],
        typeSpeed: 100,
        bacSpeed: 60,
        loop: true
       })
      </script>       

      </body>
    </html>
```

External links(for reference)
[Typed.js docs](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/)